# How to derive approximation result from Levy 0-1 law?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space. Let $\mathcal{E}_1, \mathcal{E}_2,...$ be a sequence of finite, measurable partitions of $\Omega$ such that each $\mathcal{E}_{n+1}$ is a refinement of $\mathcal{E}_n$, and assume that $\sigma(\cup_n \mathcal{E}_n) = \mathcal{F}$. Let $E_n(\omega)$ be the cell of $\mathcal{E}_n$ that contains $\omega$. For all $A$ and almost all $\omega$, the Levy 0-1 law says that
$$P(A \mid E_n(\omega)) \to \mathbf{1}_A(\omega)\tag{1}$$
In contemporary probability textbooks, this result is usually presented as an immediate consequence of the martingale convergence theorem for conditional expectations.

Interestingly, I have recently discovered a much more elementary proof of this result in Halmos's *Measure Theory* (Theorem 49.B). Besides the basic properties of conditional probability, the only result that Halmos's proof appeals to is the standard fact that measurable sets can be approximated by sets in a generating algebra. In our context, for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $n$ and $E_1,...,E_k \in \mathcal{E}_n$ such that
$$P(A \triangle E)< \epsilon, \tag{2}$$
where $E=E_1 \cup ... \cup E_k$.

From (2), Halmos's straightforwardly derives (1), which leads to my question:

> Assuming (1), is there a straightforward way to derive (2)?

We might start by noticing that $P(A \mid E_n) \to \mathbf{1}_A$ a.s. iff $P(A^c \mid E_n) \to \mathbf{1}_{A^c}$ a.s. and for all $E \in \sigma(\mathcal{E}_n)$
$$P(A \triangle E) = P(A \cap E^c) + P(A^c \cap E) = \int_{E^c}P(A \mid E_n)dP + \int_E P(A^c \mid E_n)dP.$$
Then I thought about trying something like, let $F_n = \{\omega: P(A^c \mid E_n(\omega)) < 1- \epsilon\} \in \sigma(\mathcal{E}_n)$ so that $F_n^c = \{\omega: P(A \mid E_n(\omega)) \leq \epsilon\}$. Then,
$$P(A \triangle F_n) \leq \epsilon P(F_n^c) + (1-\epsilon) P(F_n).$$
But I'm stuck here and not sure this is going to work. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I think you are on the right track by looking at the set where the conditional probability is large.  But you can be more crude.

Let $X_n(\omega) = P(A \mid E_n(\omega))$ be the conditional probability.  We are assuming $X_n \to 1_A$ a.s., but all we actually need is convergence in probability.  Let $G_n = \{X_n \ge 1/2\}$ which is $\mathcal{E}_n$ measurable and thus a finite union of the sets of that partition.  Then on $A \triangle G_n$ we have $|X_n - 1_A| \ge 1/2$, so $P(A \triangle G_n) \le P(|X_n - 1_A| \ge 1/2)$ which goes to zero by the convergence in probability.

Thus we can choose $n$ so large that $P(A \triangle G_n) < \epsilon$, and $G_n$ is the desired set.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful, as always. It never even occurred to me to try something cruder. Definitely a technique to keep in mind.